# Mod_proxy Chunk minimum file size

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I am using Apache HTTPD 2.2.17  + Mod_proxy + SSL on Ubuntu as a gateway. Everything works fine but when I send a request with `Transfer Encoding: Chunked`, it converts(de-chunk) back if the file size  is too small.

I tested with a 43k works fine. Tested with 16K and 5.5K it's getting converted as a request with 'content-length'.

My conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin *
  ServerName  *

  DocumentRoot "/var/www"
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  TransferLog /var/log/apache2/access.log

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/symantec_intermediate_ca_bundle.pem

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On  
  ProxyRequests Off
  #ProxyIOBufferSize 1024
  #SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
  #ProxyPass / http://localhost:9443/ flushpackets=on proxy-sendchunked=on
  #ProxyIOBufferSize 1024
  SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9443/ iobuffersize=1024
  #ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9443/
  #ProxyPass / http://localhost:9443/ flushpackets=on
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9443/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

httpd 2.4.1 too got the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What version of Apache is this config being used on - 2.2 or 2.4?  (looks like it won't load in 2.2)  The data at issue is in the request, not the response, correct?  Any why's it a problem to send it un-chunked?

Comment: This is from 2.4 version. Apche is used as a gateway which terminates https requests and passes to HAProxy as http. The problem is in requests not repines. This is a special requirement we need it chunked. Question is how to set Minimum chunked size in Apache or Mod_proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be this bug:
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50402

complied with patch and added :

SetEnv proxy-sendchunked

Now it's working fine :)